# Regex working in RegExr, doesn't work in PHP

Tags: php, regex

I wrote a regex in RegExr to tackle the following string:

```
<?php _on*/4353452f43f43f46 xx46 _off*/ ?>
```

This is the Regex code:

```
(.*<?php.*)(.*_on.*)(.*_off.*)(.*?>)
```

Which is working fine here:

http://regexr.com?31ptt

But it doesn't work with PHP, I get weird errors like: "Unknown modifier '<'", etc.

What do I need to do to convert this to work with PHP?

This is my php code:

```
$virusstring = '(.*/<?php.*)(.*_on.*)(.*_off.*)(.*?>)';    
if(preg_match($virusstring,$myfile)) {
    $fixed = preg_replace($virusstring,'',$myfile);
    $blah = file_put_contents($item, $fixed);
}
```

$myfile is just taken from the infected file that is being scanned.

Comment: Show us the PHP code you're trying to use.

Comment: This will be easier to troubleshoot if you show your PHP code.

Comment: PHP uses **PCRE** (PREG compatible), perhaps the *RegExr* you are using *doesn't*.

Comment: Try using [this tester](http://www.regextester.com/) and select PREG. You will see your RegEx fail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your regular expression is missing delimiters. You need to add delimiters or PHP will assume your opening `(` is a delimiter:

```
/(.*<\?php.*)(.*_on.*)(.*_off.*)(.*\?>)/
```

Also, `?` is a quantifier, matching 0 or 1 of the previous character. You need to escape it:

```
(.*<\?php.*)(.*_on.*)(.*_off.*)(.*\?>)
```

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work fine

```
preg_match("/(.*<\\?php.*)(.*_on.*)(.*_off.*)(.*\\?>)/us", $searchText)
```